# Multi Language trailing slash in url

Tags: multi-language, multilingual

I am currently using

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/system [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

to remove trailing slashes in my urls, however for some reason it does not work with the multi language module - I'm using Expression Engine 2.9.0 and Multi Language 2.0.1

Example:

```
domain.co.uk/link/ > domain.co.uk/link (trailing slash is removed)
domain.co.uk/cy/link/ > domain.co.uk/cy/link/ (trailing slash is NOT removed)
```

I realise this is legacy software but I'm just trying to maintain this site.

Answer (score 0):

Right below the RewriteEngine On line, add:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R] # <- for test, for prod use [L,R=301]
to enforce a no-trailing-slash policy.

To enforce a trailing-slash policy:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R] # <- for test, for prod use [L,R=301]